# WPF - Assign static resources into XAML array without code-behind

Tags: wpf, xaml, staticresource

I'm working on MS .NET WPF; In XAML, I've defined some static resources. I want to assign them into an array which is also declared in XAML.

Here are the static resources:

```
<local:Person x:Key="PersonABC" Name="Hello" Age="29" />
<local:Person x:Key="PersonXYZ" Name="World" Age="55" />
```

But I couldn't assign them into the array by something like `{StaticResource PersonABC}`. I've to re-create the resources and assign them into the array:

```
<x:Array x:Key="PersonList" Type="{x:Type local:Person}">
    <local:Person Name="Hello" Age="29" />
    <local:Person Name="World" Age="55" />
</x:Array>
```

But i want something like:

```
<x:Array x:Key="PersonList" Type="{x:Type local:Person}">
    "{StaticResource PersonABC}"
    "{StaticResource PersonXYZ}"
</x:Array>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StaticResource can be written in tag (element) format:

```
<x:Array x:Key="PersonList" Type="{x:Type local:Person}">
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="PersonABC"/>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="PersonXYZ"/>
</x:Array>
```

see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/staticresource-markup-extension#xaml-object-element-usage)